# AbstractUser Login View

Tags: python, django

I've spent a couple of days on this, read the docs, read some Two Scoops info, and I'm missing something. I'm trying to make a view to log in an AbstractUser. The AbstractUser model is in `my_app` and the view is in an app called `mainsite`, that I use to store project-wide views.

After the user logs in, they will have access to class-based views that they will use to add, edit, and delete database records. These users are not staff, so I am not giving them access to the admin.

Every time I try to log in as a user, `authenticate(username, password)` (in views.py) returns none.

What am I missing?

Here's the setup--I have a custom Person model that extends the AbstractUser model:

```
# my_app.models.py
class Person(AbstractUser):
    date_left = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def _full_name(self):        
        return self.get_full_name()
    full_name = property(_full_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'People'
```

I've added Person to settings.py:

```
# settings.py
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "my_app.Person"
...
```

I have the following URLconf:

```
# project/urls.py
from mainsite.views import login_view
...
url(r'^login/$', login_view, name='login'),
...
```

This view logs in the user:

```
# mainsite.views.py
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'logged_in.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', 
                {'message': 'Bad username or password'}
            )
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

And finally, here's the template with the login fields:

```
#templates/login.html
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row column"><h1>Login</h1></div>
    {% if message %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                <div class="alert callout">
                    <p>{{ message }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <label>Username
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <label>Password
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="button">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How did you create the user in the first place?

Comment: Using the admin. I found the issue: I need to create a custom UserCreationForm and UserChangeForm.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer (with help from reddit) in the docs.

[When you use AbstractUser, you need to create your own UserCreationForm and UserChangeForm.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) If you use AbstractBaseUser, then you will need to create additional forms.

I had not created these forms, and I created my users in the admin using forms automatically generated by Django. These forms did not set the password correctly. The automatically generated form probably used `user.password = 'some_password'`. The correct way to do it is `user.set_password('some_password')` .